# How to get text between dynamic created lines

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i try to get the text between dynamic created lines.

Example string,

```
KOR/4
1/FI222/24NOV/DOK
PLO
134-57623905WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
/TRY
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
/STACKI
89a7/SOMET
134-12389783WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
/TRY
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
/BLA
2736/2832
134-34389783WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
/TRY
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
/DYN
asdjadhjahd
134-57627905WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
/TRY
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
/STACKI
SSR/TROPPER5
FINAL
```

So i tried with .match() and exec().
I couldn't figure out a way to get the textual between the numbers in array

REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
// OUTPUT EXAMPLE

[0][
    134-57623905WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
    /TRY
    DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
    /STACKI
    89a7/SOMET
],
[2][
    134-12389783WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
    /TRY
    DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
    DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
    DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
    DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
    DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
    /BLA
    2736/2832
],
[3][
    134-34389783WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
    /TRY
    DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
    DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
    /DYN
    asdjadhjahd
]
```

etc..

Comment: What did you try? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors or warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to get target part of string.

```
var match = str.match(/\d{3}-.*?(?=\d{3}-|FINAL)/sg);
```

The regex select any part of string that start with digit with length 3 and end with digit with length 3

```js
var str = document.getElementById("str").innerHTML;
var match = str.match(/\d{3}-.*?(?=\d{3}-|FINAL)/sg);
console.log(match.join('\n\n'));
```

```html
<div id="str" style="display:none">KOR/4
1/FI222/24NOV/DOK
PLO
134-57623905WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
/TRY
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
/STACKI
89a7/SOMET
134-12389783WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
/TRY
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
/BLA
2736/2832
134-34389783WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
/TRY
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
/DYN
asdjadhjahd
134-57627905WINLOSE/WINNER/ROBO
/TRY
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
DIM/K0/CMT44-30-30/5
/STACKI
SSR/TROPPER5
FINAL</div>
```

Comment: This works perfect but stupid of me i copy paste the lines. The ending line is not always SSR/TROPPER5. That one is also dynamically created. So it must start on d{3} than end on d{3}.

Comment: @JohnSmiths You should show any type of string in question. However answer updated

Comment: @Mohammed, i can't see them return as separated array as in the output example of my question. I need them to split to get the as match[0], match[1] etc..

Comment: @JohnSmiths The `match` variable contain array but i converted it to string using `join()` to better showing in snippet. You can see array in http://jsfiddle.net/esmjk7u5/

Comment: @Mohammed, one last thing. Now if there is between captured area another d{3} that strips that one also example DIM/K0/CMT444-30-30/5 how to do this

Comment: @JohnSmiths So use `/^\d{3}-.*?(?=^\d{3}-|FINAL)/sg` https://regex101.com/r/AGgD5X/1